# why spring framework still does not have couchbase "analytics query" support

Tags: spring-data, analytics, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am using spring-data-couchbase-3.1.6 jar but it does not support analytics queries.
Verified in CouchbaseOperactions.java

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/couchbase/core/CouchbaseOperations.java

does anyone know any newer version which supports analytics queries?
Or any alternative to solve my issue